# updating text on canvas wxpython

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

```
canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, fig)
canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',on_pick)
canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', motion_notify_callback)
SSkey1=wx.StaticText(canvas,-1,"SS",pos=(623,42))
SSkey2=wx.StaticText(canvas,-1,"C-Red",pos=(603,52))
```

I have this code the text appears at first, however when I call `canvas.draw()` it updates the canvas but deletes the text. How can I make it so the text stays on the canvas?

Comment: why don't you use MPL text for drawing on the canvas?

Comment: an example would be nice, cannot find examples of MPL text online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an `Axes` object someplace in your code, call it `ax`

Basic:

```
ax.text(x, y, 'test')
```

([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text))

Fancy (has a lot more options [(tutorial)](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_guide.html)):

```
ax.annotate('test', (x, y))
```

([doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate)